# Upload tsv file to google colab

Tags: python, pandas, svm, google-colaboratory

TSV(Tab separated Value) extension file can't be uploaded to google colab using pandas

Used this to upload my file

```
import io
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Filename.csv']))
```

```
import io
stk = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['train.tsv']))
```

A tsv file should be uploaded and read into the dataframe stk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
import io

#firstly, upload file to colab
uploaded = files.upload()
#secondly, get path to file in colab
file_path = io.BytesIO(uploaded['file_name.tsv'])
#the last step is familiar to us
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t', header=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To save tsv file on google colab, `.to_csv` function can be used as follows:

```
df.to_csv('path_in_drive/filename.tsv', sep='\t', index=False, header=False) 

stk = pd.read_csv('path_in_drive/filename.tsv')  #to read the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a solution to your problem as it doesn't upload the files, but with this solution you can import files that are also on your google drive.

`from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
%cd /gdrive/My\ Drive/{'.//'}`

After mounting you should be able to load files into your script like on your desktop

Comment: Didn't work also didnt even worked in a jupyter notebook